# Does F# record support cyclic reference A -> B -> A?

Tags: data-structures, f#

I want to use the F# record, record Race and Runner where Race references Runner and Runner references Race. Is this possible with Records as it is with regular classes?

```
type Race = {
  raceIdentifier : int
  carriedWeightMean : decimal
  prizeMoneyPercentileCountry : int64
  noOfHorses : int
  runners : Runner list
} 

type Runner = {
  horseId : int
  finishPositionSequence : int64
  lbw : decimal
  horseNumberOfRaces : int
  mutable race : Race
}
```

I've tried using the "with" keyword but this doesn't seem to be working:

```
type Race = {
  raceIdentifier : int
  carriedWeightMean : decimal
  prizeMoneyPercentileCountry : int64
  noOfHorses : int
  race : Race
} with Runner = {
  horseId : int
  finishPositionSequence : int64
  lbw : decimal
  horseNumberOfRaces : int
  race : Race
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want 'and', not 'with'.   ..

Comment: I have a windows phone now, no need to be at the computer.  Now if I can only figure out how to type a backtick on the keyboard...`aha`, now I'm unstoppable :)

Comment: the first step is admitting you have a problem ;)

Comment: Thanks Brian. it dawned on me over the weekend. I had used 'and' before, but had it in my head that it was 'with', and so sure was I that i didn't check...